# preg_replace VS str_replace (Which one is faster?)

Tags: php, performance, preg-replace, str-replace

I 'm here after several tests for comparing speed of preg_replace & str_replace. Some documents claim that **str_replace is 2x faster** (because its simpler structure) but in my tests, each time preg_replace was faster a little!

The conditions :

```
PHP 8.1 & 7.2
Size of array : 8 millions rows
```

The average result :

```
preg_replace :  11.03159403801 s
str_replace  :  11.209521055222 s
```

And This is my sample code :

```
<?php

    //open file
    $uri = 'src.csv';

    //read csv
    $content=file_get_contents($uri);
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
    
    //set timer
    $start = microtime(true);
    
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        
        //$array [] = run_preg_replace ($line);
        $array [] = run_str_replace ($line);
        
    }
        
    
    //calc time
    $end = microtime(true) - $start;
    
    var_dump($end);
    var_dump(count($array));
    
    
    function run_preg_replace($str) { // remove new line and spaces
        
        return trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str));
    }
    
    function run_str_replace($str) { // remove new lines
        
        // Create an array with the values you want to replace
        $searches = array("\r", "\n", "\r\n");
        
        return trim(str_replace($searches,' ',$str));
        
    }
    
?>
```

So it is a rumor or my code isn't good enough for this comparision?

Comment: And have you tried processing only one character at for each function...? Rather than a regular expression which deals with multiple distinct characters and a "str_replace" which deals with all newlines. Have you tried with a single character and common for both functions...?

Comment: I assumed that regex is doing more but after your comment, I tested a single character replacement. preg_replacment is faster yet